# Comma splice in error message

Tags: bug, status-completed, error-message, 500-server-error

During an outage today, I saw:

> Stack Exchange is currently offline, we'll be back shortly!

The comma splice is grammatically incorrect and should be fixed.

Comment: [Does this make you nervous?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cMoFi.jpg)

Comment: @Won't OMG! [Fixed](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ECzLP.jpg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. I've changed the text as follows:

> Stack Exchange is currently offline. We'll be back shortly!

It will be live in the next prod build (meta: > `rev 2014.9.24.2604`, q&a: > `rev 2014.9.24.1891`).